# Textblock take same horizontal space even apply RotateTransform

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am apply RotateTransform on a textblock so that it display text vertically rather than horizontally but it take same space horizontally when it is not transfored. Please suggest solution to remove this hozitonally sapce.

```
<Border  BorderBrush="#888888" BorderThickness="0,0,2,0">
    <TextBlock FontFamily="Arial" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="15" Text="Menu" >
        <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform Angle="270" />
        </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
     </TextBlock>
</Border>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Use LayoutTranform instead of RenderTransform](http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2006/03/211105.html)

```
<Border  BorderBrush="#888888" BorderThickness="0,0,2,0">
    <TextBlock FontFamily="Arial" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="15" Text="Menu" >
        <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
            <RotateTransform Angle="270" />
        </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
     </TextBlock>
</Border>
```